# What is a "Tcl wrapper" and how does it work?

Tags: python, tcl

I am learning Python and occasionally hear the term "Tcl wrapper" thrown around and have absolutely no idea what it means.

Can anyone explain a "Tcl wrapper" is/does?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl

Comment: And, for completeness, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern explains what a "wrapper" is. A "Tcl wrapper", of course, is simply a wrapper that wraps Tcl.

Answer (score 4):

[Tcl](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/) is a full-fledged language in its own right.

Python uses Tcl/Tk for the graphical user interface,
[tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).  In this case python is a wrapper around Tcl/Tk.

Depending on the context, a Tcl wrapper could be a Tcl language wrapper
around another language, a wrapper around another API, or in the case 
of Python, a wrapper around Tcl's API.